# How to use Visual Studio 2010's advanced intellisense tooltip in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I don't know whether it is missing in Visual Studio 2012 but I wonder why I cannot see the advanced tooltip feature in 2012.

In VS2010, once you hover your mouse over a code, it displays the following:

[image]

But it is how it looks right now in Visual Studio 2012:
[image]

And it looks rather primitive compared to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: So you mean there is no more of this advanced feature?

Comment: That's not a normal VS2010 IntelliSense tooltip.  The textbox is particularly interesting.  You probably installed some add-in long ago that you forgot about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's from a Visual Studio Plug-in. I think it's either PowerTools or VSCommands. You should install the same plug-in in VS2012, and you should get that behavior back.

(Just confirmed that it's [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home) that provides that feature.)

Comment: Note that you need to enable the *Solution Navigator* feature in the plug-in for the improved tooltip to show up.